# R - quadprog package for constrained Lasso (penalized) linear regression

Tags: r, regression, lasso

**What I am doing so far:**

I am doing a constraint linear regression with R's `quadprog` package, function `solve.QP()`. The regression does not have an intercept $\alpha$, therefore the objective function can be stated by $$min_{b} (Y-Xb)^\top(Y-Xb)$$ which is the squared residuals.

Quadprog optimizes the function $$min_{b}\Big(\frac{1}{2}b^\top Db-d^\top b\Big)$$ Therefore I have to transform the first function into the second one. The end result is $$\frac{1}{2}b^\top X^\top Xb-Y^\top Xb$$ where $X^\top X =:D$ and $Y^\top X=:d$.

There are two risk factors in this example (hence Y is a vector of the dependent variable and X is a 2-dim matrix of the independent variables), whereas the first one is restricted to be greater or equal to -10 and the second one greater or equal to zero. The code for this is the following:

```
require("quadprog")

Dmat = t(X) %*% X
Amat = t(diag(2))
bvec = c(-10,0)
dvec = t(Y) %*% X

solve.QP(Dmat = Dmat, dvec = dvec, Amat = Amat, bvec = bvec, meq = 0, factorized = F)
```

---

**What I want to add:**

I want to add penalties to the regression in order to replicate a Lasso regression. Therefore, the initial objective function has to be expanded by the penalty term $\lambda |b|$ $$min_{b} (Y-Xb)^\top(Y-Xb)+\lambda |b|$$ 
In order to bring it into the form usable by the algorithm, I form it into $$\frac{1}{2}b^\top X^\top Xb-(Y^\top X-\frac{1}{2}\lambda)|b|$$
The penalty term $\lambda$ is a vector with two entries $\lambda=(80.56,5.65)$. However, when I now run the algorithm, the objective function gets negative and $b_1$ will be $b_1 = -10$, which is the most negative piossible value allowed by the constraints. $b_2$ will be $b_2=0$.

These results are not equal to results I get with the `glmnet` package which allows me to perform a Lasso regression with the same penalties. Those results have been checked and are correct. Hence, I do not know why the quadprog algorithm delivers different results. Any hints? Is the objective function wrong? Did I specify any input parameter for `quadprog` incorrectly?

Comment: just a shot: is $X$ standardized?

Comment: Yes it is standardized beforehand. Hwoever, I think this is not necessary for a regression. Just the demeaning, as I do not use an intercept.

Comment: I can't tell from your description, but the LASSO penalty should be $\lambda\sum \|b\|$. Is that what you used?

Comment: I use a specific $\lambda$ for every regression factor, therefore the $\lambda$ is on the right side of the sum sign. I forgot the sign of the absolute b values though, I added them now.

Comment: Can you please post you code after adding the sign of sum of b?